# How to set up a mail server with multiple domains (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, email, postfix, dovecot

I'm the only user on my server, so the default install of postfix/dovecot has been fine until now. But I now have 4 domains and need an email address for each of them. I would like to be able to send/receive with them via pop3 with an email client.

I was following [this decent guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixVirtualMailBoxClamSmtpHowto) until I got to the end and saw the note that it doesn't work in 12.04. I tried [this "basic setup" guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto) which starts with the gem "I assume that you know what an MX record is." (Well no, that's why I need a guide.)

There are surprisingly few guides on how to do this. I understand the security risks; it's only me on the system. A non-flexible solution (where the email addresses are set in stone at the beginning) would even be ok with me, if it was simpler.

Comment: I understand what it is, just not what it should be. I set up my server's domain (A type) and subdomain (CNAME) so I do know how to set up a DNS record, if I know what I should be pointing it to.

Comment: I'm in exactly the same situation. Do you remember what guide you finally followed, and if it all worked out for you could you please link to it here

Comment: I never did, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Virtual Mailboxes which can be used for multiple domains and then it's also easier to add other mailboxes, aliases and other future domains.

I'm running several Ubuntu LTS 12.04 servers with this configuration using Postfix/Dovecot with IMAPS - you can use pop if you want.

If this is for an external (Internet facing server) then you need to create or point your DNS records MX to your server and add the relevant host entries to your server and Postfix configuration. You need to provide more specifics about your scenario and setup so we can help you further.

Here are some tutorial guides on a mailserver setup that may help you:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin
https://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

That first guide you refer to with the section that states does not work with 12.04 and above is referring to dovecot.conf file. Here is a sample file that works with 12.04 and I believe 14.04 - you **WILL** want to modify it to suit your server especially if on the Internet and not just an internal server:

```
auth default {
  mechanisms = plain cram-md5

  user = root
  socket listen {
    client {
      # The client socket is generally safe to export to everyone. Typical use
      # is to export it to your SMTP server so it can do SMTP AUTH lookups
      # using it.
      path = /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth
      mode = 0660
      user = postfix
      group = postfix
    }
  }
}


base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.info
log_path = /var/log/dovecot
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n

passdb {
 args = /etc/dovecot/passwd
driver = passwd-file
}


protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/auth
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  chroot = login
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
  user = dovecot
}
service imap {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
}
service pop3-login {
  chroot = login
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
  user = dovecot
}
service pop3 {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
}

service imaps {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
}

service pop3s {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
}

ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

userdb {
 args = /etc/dovecot/users
 driver = passwd-file
}

valid_chroot_dirs = /var/spool/vmail
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}
```